# Json key is missing the refresh token field in google photos api

Tags: php, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am creating a app using google photos api in php. Here is my code

```
function connectWithGooglePhotos()
{
$clientSecretJson = json_decode(
    file_get_contents('credentials.json'),
    true
)['web'];
$clientId = $clientSecretJson['client_id'];
$clientSecret = $clientSecretJson['client_secret'];
$tokenUri = $clientSecretJson['token_uri'];
$redirectUri = $clientSecretJson['redirect_uris'][0];
$scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary'];

$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    'clientId' => $clientId,
    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    'redirectUri' => $redirectUri,
    'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'scope' => $scopes,
]);

// The authorization URI will, upon redirecting, return a parameter called code.
if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $authenticationUrl = $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(['access_type' => 'offline']);
    header('Location: ' . $authenticationUrl);
} else {
    // With the code returned by the OAuth flow, we can retrieve the refresh token.
    $oauth2->setCode($_GET['code']);
    $authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();
    $refreshToken = $authToken['access_token'];

    // The UserRefreshCredentials will use the refresh token to 'refresh' the credentials when
    // they expire.
    $_SESSION['credentials'] = new UserRefreshCredentials(
        $scopes,
        [
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
        ]
    );

    $photosLibraryClient = new PhotosLibraryClient(['credentials' => $_SESSION['credentials']]);
}

return $photosLibraryClient;
}
```

Here is the error while redirect to authenticate

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: json key is missing the 
>    refresh_token field in C:\xampp\htdocs\gphotos\vendor\google\auth\src\Credentials\UserRefreshCredentials.php:78 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gphotos\config.php(49): Google\Auth\Credentials\UserRefreshCredentials->__construct(Array, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gphotos\index.php(5): connectWithGooglePhotos() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gphotos\vendor\google\auth\src\Credentials\UserRefreshCredentials.php on line 78

Any solutions will be appreciated !

Comment: Robin, check my answer. Let me know if you still face any issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'refreshToken'` needs to be `'refresh_token'` because the key for refresh token is `refresh_token`

so you need to change your credentials to

```
[
   'client_id' => $clientId,
   'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
   'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
]
```

Comment: Danyal, can you please check code again and tell me why refresh token is not working. It expires after 1 hour and show me error like token revoked

Comment: what's the exception that you are getting?

Comment: Now, i m not at my pc but it said your token is expired or revoked

Comment: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "token has been expired or revoked." }

Comment: that means the refresh token has expired. You need to regenerate it

Comment: Is there a way to auto generate token when expired?

Comment: how did you get the refresh token, you need to regenerate it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'prompt' setting is set to 'consent' as shown below.

```
$url = $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri([
    'prompt' => 'consent',
    'access_type' => 'offline'
]);
```

Normally, only the first invocation of the prompt sends back the refresh token. This is by design.

However, if you need to force consent again use the above setting. This will re-generate the refresh token as well.